# Saving Learning Progress of Neural Network in Tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, save

In Python, Tensorflow: I trained and applied a Neural Network using Tensorflow, now I need to save its progress to train it further at a later point in time.

I went through a lot of configurations using

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore()
tf.train.import_meta_graph('model/model.ckpt.meta')
tf.train.export_meta_graph('model/model.ckpt.meta')
```

etc...

but it always produces an Error.

Here is my code. It is similar to the Mnist example codes, but uses custom generated input and has a single, continuous output neuron.

```
x = tf.placeholder('float', [None, 4000]) # 4000 is my structure, just an example
y = tf.placeholder('float') # And I need a single, continuous output

def train_neural_network(x):

    testdata_images, testdata_labels = generate_training_data_batch(size = 10) 
    #Generates test data

    data=[]
    for i in range(how_many_batches):
        data.append(generate_training_data_batch(size = 10))
    #Generates training data


    prediction = neural_network_model(x) 
    # neural_network_model() is defined as a 4000x15x15x10x1 neural network
    cost = tf.reduce_mean( tf.square( tf.subtract(y, prediction) ) )
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

    hm_epochs = 10 
    saver = tf.train.Saver()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            epoch_loss = 0

            for i in range(how_many_batches):
                epoch_x, epoch_y = data[i]

                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
                epoch_loss += c


                accuracy1 = tf.subtract(y, prediction)
                result = sess.run(accuracy1, feed_dict={x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})

                print(result)
                # This is just here so I can see what is going on

        saver.save(sess, 'model/model.ckpt')
        tf.train.export_meta_graph('model/model.ckpt.meta')

    tf.reset_default_graph()
```

Later in the same file I want to use the saved neural network to make some predictions with it:

```
train_neural_network(x)

X, Y = generate_training_data_batch(size = 1)

prediction = neural_network_model(x)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    tf.train.import_meta_graph('model/model.ckpt.meta')
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    thought = sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={x: X})

    print(Y, thought)
```

With this version i get the Error message

```
ValueError: Tensor("Variable:0", shape=(4000, 15), dtype=float32_ref) must be from the same graph as Tensor("Placeholder_35:0", shape=(?, 4000), dtype=float32).
```

I also got Error Messages like

```
ValueError: At least two variables have the same name: Variable/Adam
```

I am looking for a solution of this for a few weeks now, so I would be very relieved to finally get this sorted out.

Comment: Did you also try to restore placeholders? Obviously, if you do restore in the same file, Tensorflow only sees the first placeholder you defined while training and saving model. Later on, because of that, throwing an error of not being the same graph.

Comment: So you mean i should define separate placeholders for each function? Or alternatively create a separate file which uses the saved model?